# Divide one field by another field in mongoDB Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to divide cropYield by cropAcres, my data format is following and I have 1000s of them.so i need to get array of this `cropYield/cropAcres` for each of the entries as an array. this is my **FarmerCropDataLog** collection.

```
{
  "_id": "5ce681e14e8e8aec5a7e9ac4",
  "_class": "com.cheruvu.webapp.entity.FarmerCropDataLog",
  "farmerId": "5cdc16214e8e21271cb3af5e",
  "cropData": {
    "cropName": "COTTON",
    "crop": "COTTON",
    "cropAcres": 2,
    "cropYield": 10,
    "cropPrice": 9000
  },
  "villageId": "5b0ed0bd77c8ae9704f65c97",
  "creationTime": "1558610401404",
  "lastUpdated": "1558610996163",
  "state": "ACTIVE"
}
```

This is what i have tried.

```
// I need to fetch all users(farmers) with same VillageId, same crop and which are added in last year.

Criteria criteria = Criteria.where(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CROP).is(getComparisonSheet.getCrop().name())
                .and(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.VILLAGE_ID).is(villageId)
                .and(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CREATION_TIME).gte(LAST_YEAR);

MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criteria);   

// then via projection i am getting cropYield and divide it via cropAcres.

ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CROP_YIELD);
ProjectionOperationBuilder builder = new ProjectionOperationBuilder("op1", projectionOperation, null);
builder = builder.divide(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CROP_ACRES);
projectionOperation = builder.as(GetYieldComparisonResponse.Constants.MAX_YIELD);

// and at last i am running this operation via following code.
AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).explain(false)
                .cursor(new BasicDBObject("batchSize", 100)).build();
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation,projectionOperation)
                .withOptions(aggregationOptions);
        AggregationResults<GetYieldComparisonResponse> aggregationResults = farmerCropDataLogDAO
                .runAggregation(aggregation, FarmerCropDataLog.class, GetYieldComparisonResponse.class);
```

the result produced by this is empty. I dont understand why?

Comment: Could you post the raw mongo aggregate as well?

Comment: @Bajal can you elaborate? i didnot understand,

Comment: Could you post the equivalent mongo aggregate query? Then it can be mapped back to the Java API code you have written in spring-data-mongo

Comment: okay can you write an example that divides 2 fields and gives list<array> as result

Comment: added the query as answer. Hope you can write the java code for the same.

Comment: What's the problem with my java code then? I am doing the same thing

Comment: You have to determine the query produced by your java code, that is what I was asking earlier. You can try adding this to your application.properties file and see if the query gets dumped to log: logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb=DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) aggregate function like so. Add more fields to project as necessary, here I am projecting the farmerId and correspoding value for yield/acre.

```
db.FarmerCropDataLog.aggregate([
    { $project: { farmerId: 1, 
        yieldPerAcre: { $divide: [ "$cropData.cropYield", "$cropData.cropAcres" ] } } }
])
```